# How to convert this into Sequelize object query

Tags: sequelize.js

I have this sql:

```
SELECT f.*, v1."afID", v1.ext 
  FROM "Files" f
  LEFT JOIN "FileVersions" v1
      ON f.version = v1.version 
          AND v1.version = (
              SELECT MAX(v2.version) 
              FROM "FileVersions" v2
              WHERE v2."FileId" = f.id
          )
  WHERE f."deleted" = false
```

I would like to somehow convert this into the object query notation.
I've tried so many approaches, have no idea.